# anchor tag colour changes to blue once it's clicked

Tags: html, css

I'd like the link to remain green in colour when it's hover and clicked. The code I wrote works when it's hovered however, when the link is clicked it turns blue. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left topbox">
      <p class="logo">trpti</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 topbox home-btns text-center">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> Sign up </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> About us </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> FAQ </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
 .topbox {
  background-color: #584B4F;
  height: 55px;
}

.logo {
  color: #EEEAE1;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.home-btns {
  color: #EEEAE1;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #EEEAE1;
}

a:hover {
  color: #40A97B;
}

a:active {
  color: #40A97B;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

Comment: a:visited { 
    color: #40A97B;
}

Comment: @ShekharPankaj: Tried it, It changes all the links to 40A97B when the page loads. It has to be white initially and when it's hovered and clicked it has to change green.

Comment: You'll need to use some javascript to add a class.  Otherwise `:visited` is determined by the browser history.  Otherwise this makes no sense: should be white when loaded, but change when clicked - but this navigates away, so no point changing. When you come back it will be the `:visited` colour.  Please clarify all the steps and colours you are expecting at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this css:

```
a:focus {
  color: #40a97b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-md-9 topbox home-btns text-center">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active"> Sign up </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> About us </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> FAQ </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

just add active class on active link and here is css for active class

```
a:visited{color: #40A97B;}
```